# TestFlight deletes my new application builds

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, testflight

I uploaded a new version of my application to TestFlight (using xCode 11). It appeared in the list of builds but after a few minutes it was deleted. Without any errors, warnings or something else. And this version of build is not available and I should increment it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: In Feb 2020, Apple has changed the TestFlight upload policy. When you do the same old steps to upload your app to TestFlight, even though you provided the export compliance information and the iOS Build page shows your build is ready to test, it just doesn’t show up on the TestFlight app.

**You need to add an extra row in info.plist to make it work.**

> **App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption = NO**

[image]

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: **UIWebview** deprecated for the new release application so you want to change the **WKWebview** for new live build releases.

Note: Use the following delegate methods for WKWebview

```
// MARK: WKNavigationDelegate Methods
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }
```